# Bootcamp Assistant tell me it cannot read Windows Partition but I can boot into Windows

Tags: windows, mac, boot-camp

I'm running Mac Big Sur. I have a windows partition installed from Bootcamp many years ago.
I can boot into Windows with holding option key at start up.
However when I use BootCamp Assistant it tells me

> Unable to read the Windows partition

> Boot Camp Assistant was unable to verify if the Windows partition contains a Windows installation. This may be because BitLocker is enabled on the partition. If so, disable BitLocker on the disk before removing Boot Camp.

I checked in Windows BitLocker is disabled.

diskutil list says that

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         780.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨BOOTCAMP⁩                219.6 GB   disk0s3
                    (free space)                         623.5 MB   -
```

I just want to update some of my out-dated drivers but I think I can only update with BootCamp Assistant only.

So how can I make BootCamp Assistant recognize my windows partition?

I don't know if it related to this problem now but I used to have installed some tools like ntfs-3g to expose NTFS windows files to mac system. Though they are not working now. And I don't quite know how to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Press option key during boot up
You will have the options to select Windows partition.